# Restore MSSQL .bak file to an amazon RDS cloud service with encrypted procedures

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to create an RDS instance for MSSQL which went successful as per the RDS documentation for import and export.

The only draw back with this is that when using the export and import tool it doesn't import the procedures since the procedures I have are encrypted.

Someone kindly assist on the best approach or point me to the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around this by:-

1. Decrypting the MSSQl Procedures
2. Import the tables and data using Ms studio import and export tool
3. Executed the raw procedures with encryption.
4. Jump up and down cause your good to go. :)

There are a number of decryptors tools online that you can use to decrypt the procedures.